# Datatype for URI-qualified names

Tags: rdf, xml-namespaces, semantic-web

The use of `xsd:QName` is discouraged in RDF, since a literal like `"svg:circle"^^xsd:QName` is not complete without a namespace binding that resolves `svg:`, and `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` is not the only possible resolution of such a prefix. In technical terms, the value space are pairs (URI, name), but there is no universal mapping from the lexical space.

XQuery formally defines a [`URIQualifiedName`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#prod-xquery31-URIQualifiedName) which is something that could fix it: `"Q{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}circle"` would unambiguously refer to a proper value of a qualified name. However, this is not defined as a formal datatype, only a part of the grammar.

I am looking for a standardized or commonly used datatype for storing qualified names in this or similar format. I know that the common way to reduce a qualified name to a single URI is joining via `#`, producing `<http://www.w3.org/2000/svg#circle>` which is good for linking but doesn't always work – a namespace with `#` inside cannot be converted this way and I am not aware of any standard that prescribes this anyway (on the other hand, RDF/XML breaks this convention as it simply concatenates the URI and the local name). I feel the tight coupling between the URI and local name justifies storing the name of an XML element or attribute in a single literal.

One option I have is to simply treat a `QName` as an [`EQName`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#prod-xquery31-EQName) and store `"Q{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}circle"^^xsd:QName`. This might however confuse tools that look for a QName (for a preferred way of serializing an XML, for example) and it is simply invalid according to the datatype as defined in XML Schema.

XSL Transformations also define [EQNames](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/schema-for-xslt30.xsd#type_EQName), so I could stick to `"Q{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}circle"^^<http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform#EQName>`. The downsides of this is that the datatypes are only defined in a non-normative schema and it is non-trivial to reach the definition from the namespace URI.

Are there other options?

Comment: I have just found [this](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-xml-schema-comments/2009JulSep/0077.html) report, whose replies suggest that such a type could make it into XML Schema 1.2.